# How to replace all Capital letters with asterisk?

Tags: c#, string

This is what i have under button 1.. I am entirely new to this program. am I missing something? there is no errors but button does no fill its purpose and doesn't change "A" to asterisk aka *. I eventually want to replace all capital letters in a word with *, but for now I just want to learn how to do the letter "A".

```
string orgstring = textBox1.Text;
string Asteriskstring = textBox1.Text.Replace("A","//*");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it, although I don't know what the forward slashes are for, and `orgstring` is redundant in this example; the result is held by `Asteriskstring`, so assuming you want to display that value you will need to update the UI:

```
textBox1.Text = Asteriskstring;
```

Comment: well thanks! It works now... is there anyway i can make this work for all capital letters and not just  the capital letter A? or would i have to use something other than Replace?

Answer (score 1):

```
string sSource = "AcccADFGHcsdD";
string sDest = Regex.Replace(sSource, @"[A-Z]", "*");
```

will return:

> "*ccc*****csd*"

In your case:

```
string orgstring = textBox1.Text;
string Asteriskstring = Regex.Replace(orgstring, @"[A-Z]", "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the contents of the textbox? If so...

```
        string textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("A","//*");
```

**Edit:** The best way would probably be to combine Arie's answer and my original answer. You want to use their regular expression replacement to change the textbox's text; the text is both your source AND destination, so:

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, "[A-Z]", "*");
```

If this doesn't work, the namespace containing the `Regex` class might not be included in your program. The `Regex` class is located in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace. To enable use of the `Regex` class, add the code below to the part of your code containing all the statements starting with `using`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: yes i am. but I eventually want to Change From not just using A but A-Z how can that be done?